# Pycaret cannot imported due to another import error

Tags: python, pycaret

ImportError: cannot import name '_joblib_parallel_args' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' (c:\users\ezgi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py)

To fix I update sklearn library. But, it don't work. Anyone know the reason behind it?

I update sklearn with
`pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`
Also, uninstall and install it with pip.

Comment: Please reformat your question. Please provide details how you upated your `sklearn` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because one of pycaret's dependencies (imbalanced-learn) fails with the latest version of sklearn

https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/894

A temporary workaround until this is fixed would be to use a lower version of sklearn. If you are using pip install pycaret, then you need to use a version of sklearn < 1.0.0